# Generate and Store random Path in openFST

Tags: c++, automata, openfst

I'm trying to use openFST to generate a very large amount of random paths and get the word and the weight of the word and store both variables in a .csv-file.
But I'm struggling to figure out how to use openFST for it. I have my .fst-file and am able to generate random paths using the fstrandgen-function but I do not know where to go from here.

Any hint towards the right direction would help me a lot!